# SQL Server all(select ...) is null

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, isnull

I search but i cannot find anything about it. I need SQL server query like

```
select t1.x 
 from @tablename as t1 
 where all
   (select t2.y from @tablename as t2 where t1.x=t2.x) is null
```

`@tablename`'s are same

But I can't use `all(select ...) is null` part of query.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you want to `select`?

Comment: Do i understand this correct? You have a table with multiple rows with identical x value, but you only want it if all rows have y is null? Or other way around, when there is a row for an x value where y has also a value, you dont want the x?

Comment: I had tried to select x values of rows whose all y values are null in a table. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `not exists`?

```
select t1.x 
from @tablename as t1 
where not exists (select t2.y from @tablename as t2 where t1.x = t2.x)
```

This tests that there are no matching values.

Or, perhaps,

```
select t1.x 
from @tablename t1 
where not exists (select 1
                  from @tablename as t2
                  where t1.x = t2.x and t2.y is not null
                 ) ;
```

This tests that any matching value has `NULL` for `y`.

Comment: Very good approach that is never occur to beginner like me. Thanks a lot.